# Changing default encoding of vim to utf-8 not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, encoding, utf-8

I've been trying to change the default encoding of vim by writing in the $HOME/.vimrc file the following lines

```
set fileencodings=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

I understand that the first line makes vim try to read a file with utf-8 encoding and the second line makes vim save files always with an utf-8 encoding. But when I write a file called example.txt and write no special characters, I save it to verify

```
 file -i example.txt
```

output:

```
example.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

If I wrote then special characters on example.txt then it would display correctly

```
example.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

But I want always the encoding to be utf-8 even if the file does not have special characters. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 4):

`file` looks at the content of the file to determine its encoding. If it only finds ASCII characters it can only conclude that the file is ASCII.

ASCII being a subset of UTF-8 (the basis of a number of other encodings), it is simply impossible for any program to tell if `123abc` is anything other than ASCII.

Of course, if you add UTF-8 characters to that file, `file` will spot them and act accordingly.

So… on to the Vim side of the "problem".

`fileencodings` is a list of encodings considered by Vim when reading a file.

`fileencoding` is the encoding used by Vim when writing a specific file.

The default value of both options depends on the value of `encoding`, which is set during startup.

The "ideal" `encoding` is `utf-8`. With this, you get a sensible list for `fileencodings`: `ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`, and a sensible value for `fileencoding`: `utf-8` that pretty much guarantee a smooth experience as long as you stay within the confines of UTF-8.

See:

```
:help 'encoding'
:help 'fileencodings'
:help 'fileencoding'
```